# How to avoid repetition of rhymes in poetry, yet maintain the rhythm?

Tags: creative-writing, poetry, breaking-bad-writing-habits

I do very well in writing short stories but when it comes to poetry I'm faced with the problem of repeating the same rhymes. I always want my poems to have a particular sequence of rhythm, but while trying to get a new rhythm for a new line I end up using a similar word already used in previous lines. Please how can I avoid the repetition of rhymes in my poetry and still be in track with the original rhythm?

Comment: I don't see how "tautology" means anything here. It means "saying the same thing in different words" (not similar words) or "a statement that is true by necessity or by its logical form." It has nothing to do with words in similar rhythm or rhyme, or even repeating the **same** word (different words are a necessity of tautology). Other than that, I think this is asking "what to write."

Comment: Thanks Amadeus, I gave a closer look into the word tautology and figured that I had used it out of context here. Thanks for your keen observation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every verse in a poem should be carefully constructed. If on the first try you write a verse that matches the above verses, then you should revise and think of a different verse. Maybe a different way to express yourself.

- Use a thesaurus. Let's say you want to have a word to rhyme with *way*. There are lots of words that rhyme with *way*. *Hey, hay, gray, may, say, etc.*
- Use inversion. Sometimes, you may have a verse that ends with *orange*. It's hard to find anything that rhymes with *orange*, so you switch the verse around. This may change the emphasis of the verse or the meter of the verse.
- Think metaphorically. If the current verse is not working for you, then you may revise and start thinking more metaphorically. By thinking metaphorically, you may compare the concept to something else, and that something else may be easier to find words for.
- Read aloud. Poetry is meant to be read aloud for rhyme and meter. English is a stress-timed language. Other languages may be syllable-timed. If your native language is syllable-timed, then you may need a native English speaker to read aloud for you. You may alternatively write a poem in your native language and translate the poem yourself, sacrificing some aspect of the original poem. Even if you ask a native English-speaking buddy who also speaks your native language natively or at a very high level, then something of the original poem must be sacrificed to sound good in the English version. Poetry is one of those untranslatable things, because it relies on the linguistic properties of the source language, which may not exist in the target language.

Comment: *"Use a thesaurus. Let's say you want to have a word to rhyme with way."* I don't think I've ever seen a thesaurus that lists words that rhyme with a given word. There are lists of those, too, obviously, just not there... I think. :)

Comment: Thanks Double U, you have made things easier and better for me. I'll look into all your suggestions and stick with the one that works best for me. Thanks

Comment: @MichaelKjörling The thesaurus can provide synonyms of the word you have in mind, and the synonyms may be easier to work with.